# Vue web-component conflicts with symbols of other frameworks

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, web-component

I like to extend a website which uses jQuery with a component written in vue3 but the script file build by vite clutters the namespace and causes conflicts.

Currently I'm exporting the component as a web-component via `defineCustomElement`.
However, I have the problem, that certain symbols, in my case the `EMPTY_OBJ` symbol from `@vue/shared`, lie in the global scope and are sometimes replaced by the minifier with the symbol `$`.
This breaks a lot of code in the website, as it conflicts with the common jQuery alias `$`.

For reproduction just `npm create vue@latest` with default settings and `npm run build` and the produced javascript contains for example

```
**/function Cn(e,t){const n=new Set(e.split(","));return t?s=>n.has(s.toLowerCase()):s=>n.has(s)}const U={},Je=[],ue=()=>{}
```

In this case the minifier chose `U` as a symbol, but in some other cases it chooses `$`.

Any idea how to solve this, e.g. by building the extension in such a way to keep its symbols in a local scope?

Comment: The obvious solution is to import $ everywhere it's used in modules